# pm2 crash after this command pm2 restart all

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs app sometimes I want to restart the app . but when I write `"pm2 restart all"` pm2 crached and pm2's list is removed. also I've written a cron-start into pm2 beacuse the app will slow after a few hours and server's memory is full, that's why I've written cron-start and Do you Know about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using PM2 improperly and there are a few problems. Let's dissect them:

1. "pm2 restart all" causes PM2 to fail and removes the list: There are numerous explanations for why this might be occurring. It's possible that PM2 has a bug that's causing it to fail. Another option is that PM2 is crashing because of your Node.js application. You can test running your app without PM2 to see if it crashes, and you can also look through PM2's logs to see if any error messages are present, in order to fix this problem.
2. Your app slows down and uses up too much memory: This is a common issue with Node.js apps, especially if they are running for long periods of time. One solution is to periodically restart your app, which is what you are attempting to do with "pm2 restart all". However, this can cause issues if PM2 crashes, as we discussed in the first point.

You might think about adding some memory management techniques in your Node.js application to solve this problem. For instance, you could use a program like Node.js' integrated heapdump module to capture periodic snapshots of how much memory your app is using and examine them to find memory leaks. You can also use a program like the Node.js module "node-memwatch" to track the memory utilization of your app in real-time and notify you when it exceeds predetermined limits.

A cron-start has been entered into PM2 by you: What you mean by this is not entirely obvious. This is a good tactic for dealing with the memory problem we previously discussed if you're using PM2's cron feature to routinely restart your app. The cron feature of PM2 may cause problems with PM2 crashing, though, if you're using it in some other manner.

In general, it's challenging to offer precise guidance without knowing more about your app and its usage habits. However, as this is probably the main reason for the issues you're having with PM2, I would advise looking into the RAM issue in your app first.

Comment: I ran it with nodemon without pm2  and it worked well sometimes pm2 restart all worked but dometimes it crached

Comment: @farshid.chegini cron might be the problem when used with pm2.

Comment: if I update pm2 to latest version is it possible that it does well

Comment: @farshid.chegini I am not 100% sure will that work or not but it's better to give a try, also I would recommend you try some memory management technique to improve the workload